# Why are checks failing in my Foundry Code Repository after copying from external repo?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

The following error observed during the check's execution in master branch (and every branch inherited from it).

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project. 
    > Failed to apply plugin 'com.palantir.transforms-defaults'. 
    > ChecksException: 
       (TransformsGradlePlugin:NoProjectVersionSet):
        {hint=No project version was set, possibly because there are no git tags., project=clinical-trials-anonymised-repo}
```

Initially code in this repo was copied from another repo via Windows git cli (git clone $old_repo → copy-paste → git push $new_repo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When receiving this error you should go to Branches > Tags > New tag > Create a tag "0.0.1" from branch "master". Then create an empty commit on master, and ensure you merge master into all other branches you want to use. Next time you clone a repo like this, make sure you also push the tags.